# adding ipv6 addresses to loopback sub interfaces

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet

I have Ubuntu 20.04. I have three distinct loopback interface lo:11, lo:12 and lo:13. I want to assign a unique ipv6 address to each of those loopback interfaces and advertise them with bgp(v6).

The problem is that when I add loopback interfaces as follows, the ipv6 address is getting added to the main 'lo' interface and not to the intended loopback lo:12.

```
$ sudo ifconfig lo:12 inet6 add 2004:db8::2/64
```

```
root@1ebe278172fd:/go/src/app# ifconfig lo:12

lo:12: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 12.12.12.1  netmask 255.255.255.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)

root@1ebe278172fd:/go/src/app# ifconfig lo

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        **inet6 2004:db8::2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>**
        inet6 2003:db8::2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

How to overcome this?

I want different loopback interfaces with different ipv6 addresses to test route advertisement via bgpv6, not everything on lo main interface.

Note: It is working fine for ipv4 addresses.